# Write MemoryStream to URL

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have a `MemoryStream` and I need to write it out to a URL.

I've been looking into `WebClient.UploadFile`.  However, all its overloads seem to require a filename, which I don't have.

My file is serialized as a Stream.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: There are many ways to POST data in .Net. I'll give you some google terms: HttpClient, HttpWebRequest

Comment: Use an instance of `StreamContent` with `HttpClient`.

Comment: You can use something like `new HttpClient().PutAsync("http://your.url", new StreamContent(yourMemoryStream))` (with proper disposing of `HttpClient` and `StreamContent`). Or `PostAsync` if POST request is expected.